# Can I generate a 500 or 501 error from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, http

I want to test an error landing page that handles HTTP 500 and 501 responses.

I can do that easily in my ASP.NET code, but I'd like to avoid deploying server-side code in this scenario.

Is it possible to trigger an HTTP 500 or 501 from JavaScript?  If so, how?

Comment: You could redirect to your error landing page, but what how is the client going to determine a 500/1 if there is no request/response to interpret? Perhaps expanding on your question and listing the criteria that drives the logic and/or your use case would be a little more helpful.

Comment: Technically, Node.js _is_ JavaScript. So the question should rather ask for client-side JavaScript, IMO.

Comment: @MarkC. C: I can indeed redirect to the error page.  What I'm really testing here is a framework we have which should redirect to our landing page in case of any 500/501 error.  I believe I have it set up correctly, but I need to produce a 500/501 to actually confirm that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With javascript you can't do that: 5xx - server-side generated errors

[Wikipedia about 5xx errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.
It's necessarily the role of the HTTP server. :-/

Answer (score -1):

In a one line : No it is not possible

```
5XX is Insternal Server Issue
```

500 Internal Server is a generic error message, given when no more specific message is suitable

If you are using `.htaccess` it may and configuration error may led to give this issue.

Or if your PHP script makes too many network connection , the connections may time out . So there also you may come across `500 Internal Server Error`